# Tweepy: Getting "Fail" Output When Fetching Tweets Despite Correct Implementation

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

Question:
I am using the Tweepy library in Python to fetch tweets using their tweet IDs. I have followed the documentation and various tutorials to set up my code correctly, but I keep getting the "Fail" output for some of the tweets. I would appreciate any insights into why this might be happening. Here is the code I am using:

```
import tweepy
    import json

    consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
    consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
    access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
    access_secret = 'YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    tweet_ids = twitter_archive.tweet_id.values
    count = 0
    fails_dict = {}

    with open('tweet_json.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for tweet_id in tweet_ids:
            count += 1
            print(f"{count}: {tweet_id}")
            try:
                tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id, tweet_mode='extended')
                json.dump(tweet._json, outfile)
                outfile.write('\n')
                print("Success")
            except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                print(f"Fail: {e}")
                fails_dict[tweet_id] = str(e)

    print("Finished fetching tweets.")
```

[image]

Despite providing the correct consumer key, consumer secret, access token, and access secret, tweets fail to be fetched, and I receive the error message output by `print(f"Fail: {e}")`. I have ensured that the tweet IDs are valid and present in the tweet_ids list.

Could anyone please help me understand why I am encountering this issue? Are there any additional steps or considerations that I might be missing while fetching tweets using Tweepy? Any suggestions or insights would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to call the **Twitter API v1.1**, which can only be used for **Media Uploads**.

For the **Tweet lookup feature** (which requires **Basic Level Access**), you should call the **Twitter API v2**.

Replace:

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

with the following code snippet:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)
```

And, also replace:

```py
tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id, tweet_mode='extended')
```

with the following code snippet:

```py
# Get tweet
tweet = client.get_tweet(id=tweet_id)
```

You may need to make some more modifications to your code to get the correct output.

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_tweet

I hope this helps.